# How to reverse map multiple members of an entity that are mapped explicitely in Automapper C#?

Tags: c#, automapper

I work on a C# app in which I need to map 2 entities. So, I define Create map as below:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name.First))                                                                                           
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name.Last))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SSN, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.SSN))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.HomePhoneNo, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.HomePhoneNumber()))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Address))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MaritalStatus, map => map.MapFrom(src => (int)src.MaritalStatus))
```

Now, I want to do ReverseMap, but when I add .ReverseMap for each member, in the next line member, the src and dest are switched. So, is there any way to do ReverseMap for all members in just one place?

Comment: Have you tried to add `ReverseMap()` at the end of all calls?

Comment: I added ReverseMap() at the end of each line; like this:
.ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name.First)).ReverseMap()                                                                                           
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name.Last)).ReverseMap()
but for the LastName, It throws an error since the src and dest are switched...

Comment: Yes but what if you just do it after the **last** `ForMember()`?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried that, the thing is that I cannot test this part of API... so not sure if this works for all or not.

Comment: Have you tried that for several members and it worked? if yes, so I can do that for all my members.

Comment: I'm currently reproducing this. Hang on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put only one `ReverseMap()` to the end of all custom mappings.

This works for me:

```cs
using AutoMapper;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<X, Y>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar1, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Foo1))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar2, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Foo2))
            .ReverseMap()                ;                
        });
        configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
        var x1 = new X() {  Foo1 = "1", Foo2 = "2"};
        var mappedY = mapper.Map<Y>(x1);
        var againX = mapper.Map<X>(mappedY);
        Console.WriteLine($"{againX.Foo1} {againX.Foo2}");
    }
}

class X
{
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }
    public string Foo2 { get; set; }
}

class Y
{
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
    public string Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```